# Dynamically insert macro into a new excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

How can an existing macro be inserted into a new excel workbook?

I want to create a new `WorkBook` (with [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)), and then place an existing macro into the new WorkBook.

Comment: you are creating  your workbook dynamically with VBA? You can either create your workbook from a template (easy way) or add dynamically VBA inside the new created workbook (hard way)

Comment: I agree with JMax. Something to note is that VBA that can be replicated is sometimes blocked as a potential virus (this happened to me some years back, I think it was detected as a Bloodhound heuristic virus) . What code do you need to add?

Comment: I need to parse some excel files for make big one workbook (contains price list). It must have macro for make order form (generate a new one excel file with selected positions list)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The two options that JMax mentioned:

***`"hard way"`***

- Pearson's [Copy a module from one project to another](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/VBE.aspx)

***`"easy way"`***

- Use your existing workbook with the UserForm as a template to create the new WorkBook

  1. Save the existing workbook as is (to preserve your current file)
  2. Strip out any unwanted sheets
  3. If you need to strip out any code then you are effectively back to the first option as you will need Pearson's [Deleting A Module From A Project / Deleting A Procedure From A Module](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/VBE.aspx)
  4. Save as a new file

We would need to see a sample of your workbook to provide further detailed help.

Comment: Thanks to all. I use a template to create workbook with macro. Works fine.