# Inserting a module into a new workbook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vbide

I've had a trawl around the net and can't seem to find a simple solution to this one so hopeing you can help.

I have a Macro at the moment which takes data from a .txt file and overwrites an excel file with the latest data every 3 minutes. It names the new file using the date and time of the overwrite.

What i would like is for the workbook with the 'create new workbook' macro to also add a new module into each new workbook as it is created, including a pre-written macro inside the module (The inserted module will include code to record who and when the workbook is opened and closed by so will be writing into a third workbook, but i can do that bit)

I'm hoping that all of this can be done with a second Sub!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635231/dynamically-insert-macro-into-a-new-excel-workbook

Comment: Why not just create a template workbook which contains all the needed components, and write your data to that file?

Answer (score 10):

I'll get you started with adding a new module to a workbook, but can't possibly write everything for you.

We'll be using the VBA Extensibility library (VBE). It contains the definitions of the objects that make up the `VBProject`. So, before you start, make sure to add this reference:

> Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3

to your workbook. To do that, in the VBA editor go the the *Tools* menu and choose *References*. In that dialog, scroll down to and *check* the entry for *Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3*. If you don't set this reference, you will receive a compiler error.

You also need to enable programmatic access to the VBA Project. To do that (in Excel 2010 -- similar steps for other versions), go to File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings... > Macro Settings and tick *Trust access to the VBA project object model*.

And now you're ready for the code:

```
Public Sub AddNewModule()

  Dim proj As VBIDE.VBProject
  Dim comp As VBIDE.VBComponent

  Set proj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
  Set comp = proj.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
  comp.Name = "MyNewModule"

  Set codeMod = comp.CodeModule

  With codeMod
    lineNum = .CountOfLines + 1
    .InsertLines lineNum, "Public Sub ANewSub()"
    lineNum = lineNum + 1
    .InsertLines lineNum, "  MsgBox " & """" & "I added a module!" & """"
    lineNum = lineNum + 1
    .InsertLines lineNum, "End Sub"
  End With

End Sub
```

This will add a new standard module, called "MyNewModule" to the active workbook and hardcode a little sub called "ANewSub" that, when run, simply shows a message box.

I trust and hope you can take this and build on it.