# Using VBA to Setup Excel to 'Print Workbook' As Default Print Setting

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, printing

### My Question

*I'm looking for a way in VBA to set a workbook to 'Print Workbook' rather than worksheet.*

### My Roadblocks

*Can't use an AutoExec macro in the workbook itself, as this is a procedurally-generated .xls*

I have ACCESS VBA code that exports query results into an Excel document. That same VBA code then opens the Excel document, formats the .xls file and adds a few extra things (Headers, Footers, Freezes header rows in specific worksheets, etc). Then closes the .xls until the end users opens it later.

*Can't use `ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut`*

The end user typically needs to print NOTHING, or THE ENTIRE WORKBOOK (they almost never print a single worksheet). I know I can instantly print out all worksheets by adding to the end of my sub:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
```

however, this is NOT what I want. I have users at multiple locations, some of which need to print, some of which don't. So I'd like to leave the option to print up to the individual users.

Thus what I'm looking to do is make it so when the end user does need to MANUALLY print the document, it is already set to print the entire workbook and not the selected worksheet. I know the user can manually do that extra click, but we've had some users just hit print and say "we're missing information" when in fact they just didn't print the entire workbook -- I'd like to eliminate this issue.

So with all of that said...
***Is there a way in VBA to set 'Print Workbook' as the default print setting?***

Comment: Could you simply use `Workbook_BeforePrint` with `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Select`? That way, when they go to print, whether or not they choose "Entire workbook" it will print all of the sheets.

Comment: @TheEngineer - Two issues with that: 1) I'd prefer not to 'force' the user to always print everything if they do print. However, I'd be willing to do it if I had to... however that wouldn't get me around issue... 2) there really isn't an elegant way to run **any** (not just AutoExec) macros in a generated .xls file. Only 'ok' solution I could fine would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635231/dynamically-insert-macro-into-a-new-excel-workbook which would break about 90% of my code and run much more inefficiently.

Comment: Oh my mistake. I missed your note that this a "procedurally-generated .xls". Excel does not have a built-in way of setting the "Print what" to "Entire workbook". Have you considered using an add-in with a printing ribbon? That would probably not be a very elegant solution either, though.

Comment: do your users run the code in Access to create the workbook? If so, add an option or checkbox on the Access Form (I assume) to choose whether they want to print or not and then write the code to print in Access.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - Good idea, but unfortunately no. The Access code is triggered by a batch which is called by TaskScheduler on a VM. Thus no human intervention until it reaches the end user.

Comment: @TMY - Ok. So it's a "procedurally-generated.xls". Since Access creates the ".xls" file, you can then add code that will add code the ".xls" file to set the print settings. I know in your question you said that solution would break your code, but would it really, if you wrote a separate small procedure and ran it after the rest of your code was run in the batch file? You have [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) in the other question ou referenced, but providing it again, just in case it helps.